# Is there a way for Postman to display the exact line number where the error happened in console?

Tags: postman

I have difficulty troubleshooting my code in prerequest and test tab because whenever I encounter error, postman does not display in the console the exact line number where the error happened.

[Console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjrX2.png)

Is there a way to display the exact line number where the error occurred in postman console?

Comment: Nope already raised a feature request for the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get line of error/assertionError in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73492154/get-line-of-error-assertionerror-in-postman)